# Read all byte from InputStream

Tags: java, tcp, inputstream

I want to asynchronously read all bytes from the InputStream of an active tcp connection. There could be nothing in the inputbuffer, in this case I want an empty byte array[] and NOT a read/timeout.

I tried this:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(tcpInputStream);
```

But if there is nothing in the InputStream the read hangs until the tcp timeout and then an exception is thrown.

Comment: IOUtils is not in the standard library ... so what is it and does it offer an asynchronous version?

Comment: If you only want to read the data that is *immediately* available, that's what the `available()` call is for. It's rarely useful though...

Comment: @dsh: I assume it's apache commons-io. I don't have an answer to this, however, I have found two stackoverflow questions which may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833068/async-commons-io-operations and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049319/how-to-create-a-java-non-blocking-inputstream-from-a-httpsurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

You can use non blocking SocketChannels:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

...

SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 80));
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = socketChannel.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        Thread.sleep(1000); // do usefull stuff
    else {
        // use the bytes and prepare the buffer for next read
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
socketChannel.close();
```

Also prepare for a `IOException` when the server closes the connection.